# how to loop all rows in jquery grid

Tags: jquery

I have this code right now to get the row value from jquery grid..

```
$("#table1").click(function(e) {
                var row = jQuery(e.target).parent();
                value = row.attr("id");
```

I need to loop all the rows to get the values.

Can anyone help me out that? if I click on second row I need get second row value, if I click on first row I need to get first row value.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$('tr', '#table1').live('click', function(){
    var id = $(this).attr('id');
});
```

Comment: I would strongly recommend to use  $('#table1').delegate('tr', 'click', function(){});

Comment: Why? I cannot find any difference. Both binds click to the #table1 element and checks event target from there on.

Comment: Actually, if you take a look at the jQuery 1.4.2 source code, on lines 2411-2413, the only thing that the delegate extension does is to call $.fn.live on the context.